# Wordpress plugin to use against hacking

Tags: wordpress, security

My new wordpress web site has been hacked after 2 weeks after his opening .
They wrote :"hacked by ****"
I changed my password and i asked HTTPS security for my web site.
After one week has been hacked again.
Now it's the third time, please i need help, do you know any security plugin to buy to protect my wordpress web site?

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS wont protect you from getting hacked. You need to figure out how the hack is happening before you can prevent it.

I would recommend using [Sucuri](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner/) as a first line of defense and then see if you're still getting hacked. Other things I would do is make sure that all the wordpress files and your plugins are unmodified and from the original source. If your files/plugins have been compromised, it wont matter as you'll keep getting hacked.

Also make sure the theme you're using doesnt have any security holes/flaws.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved with patience and you must follow several steps.
In my opinion: 
1. First check the file and folder permission. Files must be 644 and folder must be 755. Do it with filezilla i think it is very ease. Search youtube for tutorial.
2. Intall Wordfence.
3. Move wp-config.php outside public_html folder.
4. Check all themes header.php and footer.php for suspicious code snippets.